# How can I load a glb into the forge viewer from a Google Cloud signed url?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I'm passing a Google Cloud signed url for pointing to a glb to the Forge Viewer and getting a 403 response.

```js
engine!.loadModel(glbUrl, {env: 'Production'});
```

After looking carefully at the URL being requested in the network panel, it appears the `Signature` query parameter value is having its value passed through `encodeURI` which I believe is causing Google Cloud to reject the request.

Is there a way preserve the URL when passing it to Forge or is there another way to pass credentials through?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer for this.  Here's three ideas:

**1. PROXY SERVER**

SignedURLs should just work out the box, but if GC is rejecting it, then, not going to work without some tricks, like a proxy service.
ie. create a bounce through server that removes the authentication requirement.

---

**2. MOVE TO FORGE BUCKET**​

Alternatively, I moved the glb to a forge bucket, and the Viewer added the Auth header automatically.  All I provided was the seed file to the glb file, like this:
​
​

```
// Add GLB scan to the scene, with scale and position
        viewer.loadModel("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/multi-model-demo/objects/shrewbury-orig.gltf", null,  (model)=>{
            let mat4 = (new THREE.Matrix4()).scale({x:100,y:100,z:100}).setPosition({x:3000,y:0,z:-404});
            model.setPlacementTransform(mat4);
        });
```

Here's the running example:

​https://codepen.io/wallabyway/pen/NWzoRgy
​

---

**3. TOKEN HACK**​

An experimental approach, is to hack the ACCESS-TOKEN that the viewer uses in it's fetch requests, at run-time.
​
First, load a Revit model first (as normal).

Next, force a Google access-token, and then do a loadModel() of your glb file, like this:
​

````
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.token.accessToken = "autodesk-token-here"
await loadModel(URN_Revit_Model);
await sleep(5000);
​
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.token.accessToken = "google-token-here"
await loadModel("https://cdn.google.com/storage/objects/mymodelhere.gltf");
await sleep(5000);
​```

​
​
````

Comment: Unfortunately, the gltf loader code is not ideal.  It needs to see glb or glTF in the file name.    Which means any encoding won’t work.  
Should I put in a request to have this fixed?